# Dynamically create members of interface

Tags: c#, reflection, mvp

I have a View, that implements an interface.

I'm trying to unit test this, but it gets boring...

The declaration is:

```
public interface IView : IBaseView
{
    TextBox ClientId { get; set; }
    TextBox ClientName { get; set; }
    Button SaveClient { get; set; }
    Button NextClient { get; set; }
    Button PreviousClient { get; set; }
    Button DiscardChanges {get;set;}
    bool ReadOnly { get; set;  }
    ListBox MyLittleList { get; set; }
}

    [Test]
    public void FirstSteps()
    {
        var sessionFactory = Substitute.For<ISessionFactory>();
        var session = Substitute.For<ISession>();
        var statelessSession = Substitute.For<IStatelessSession>();
        sessionFactory.OpenSession().Returns(session);
        sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession().Returns(statelessSession);

        var view = Substitute.For<IView>();

        view.ClientId = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        view.ClientName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        view.DiscardChanges = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        view.MyLittleList = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        view.NextClient = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        view.PreviousClient = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        view.ReadOnly = false;
        view.SaveClient = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    }
```

Is there a view for me to dynamically do that?

Pass the View to a method, that will verify what is there and automatically call a constructor on and set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not fully sure what you are looking for but maybe this might help a bit?:

```
public static void SetData<T>(T obj)
{
  foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    if (property.CanWrite && property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
    {
      object val = null;

      //// Optionally some custom logic if you like:
      //if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
      //    val = "Jan-Peter Vos";
      //else

        val = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);

      property.SetValue(obj, val, null);
    }
}

[Test]
public void FirstSteps()
{
  // .. Your code ..

  SetData(view);
}
```

Comment: I want to follow the DRY principle. This is just one view. I'll have more. The other view has 20 controls. But since I don't know much about reflection I decided to ask for help. I'm away from my developer machine now. As soon as I'm on it and I can test I'll tell you if it worked. Thank you anyway.